# Oracle cursor looping another cursor on a same table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to query on same table and process using cursor.
The houseno is unique and can exists only as a single record in addressRecords table.
When the program is compiles, the USERS tablespace grows rapidly and fills up the disk space quickly.
Is there a better way of writing?

```
DECLARE
    plc VARCHAR2(200); 
    cly VARCHAR2(200);
    roadno VARCHAR2(200); 
    houseno VARCHAR2(200);
    owner VARCHAR2(200);
    tenant VARCHAR2(200);,
    name VARCHAR2(200);
    address_query VARCHAR2(4000);
    houseno_query VARCHAR2(4000);
    addressRecords NUMBER := 0;
    address_cursor sys_refcursor;
    houseno_cursor sys_refcursor;
    hno_counter NUMBER := 0;
    
BEGIN
    
    houseno_query :='SELECT DISTINCT PLOTNO FROM CITY ORDER BY PLOTNO';
    select count(*) INTO addressRecords from CITY;
    
    OPEN houseno_cursor FOR houseno_query;
    IF (addressRecords = 0) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20505, 'no entries found');
    END IF;
    
    LOOP
        
        FETCH houseno_cursor INTO houseno;
        
        EXIT WHEN houseno_cursor%notfound;  
        
        
        address_query :='SELECT PLOTNO,STREETNO,COLONY,AREA,OWNEDBY,RENTEDBY,IDENTITY FROM CITY WHERE PLOTNO=houseno';
        OPEN address_cursor FOR address_query;
        
        LOOP
            
            FETCH address_cursor INTO houseno, roadno, cly, plc, owner, tenant, name;
            
            -- print houseno
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processing house number : ' || houseno);
            -- Insert unique house numbers
            IF (hno_counter = 0) THEN
                INSERT INTO HOUSEDETAILS
                    VALUES (houseno, roadno, cly, plc);     

            END IF;
            
            INSERT INTO PERSONDETAILS
                VALUES (houseno, roadno, cly, plc, owner, tenant, name);
            
            hno_counter := hno_counter + 1;
            
        END LOOP;
    
        CLOSE address_cursor;   
        
    END LOOP;   
        
    CLOSE houseno_cursor;
    
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you could write it down much more easy. 
I notice you are opnening the same (big?) table a few times. I wrote a small part of code that might give you a idea on how you could also do this. I moved your SELECT statements to a cursor, that one I open and I loop through those. If there are no more records the cursor loop will end automaticly.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cCity IS
        SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY PlotNo;
BEGIN

    FOR rCity IN cCity LOOP
        --
        INSERT INTO HouseDetails(ColumnA, ColumnB)
        VALUES(rCity.HouseNo, rCity.RoadNo);
        
        --Here you can also do an insert into PersonDetails table.
        
    END LOOP;
    
    COMMIT;
    
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Tenzin for your input. I have one issue with persons living on same house numbers.
I cannot Insert duplicate house number into HouseDetails.

Comment: Input details:

PLOTNO;STREETNO;COLONY;AREA;OWNEDBY;RENTEDBY;IDENTITY
111;STREET111;COLONY111;AREA111;OWNEDBY111;RENTEDBY111;IDENTITY111
121;STREET121;COLONY121;AREA121;OWNEDBY121;RENTEDBY121;IDENTITY121
123;STREET123;COLONY123;AREA123;OWNEDBY123;RENTEDBY123;IDENTITY123
123;STREET123;COLONY123;AREA123;OWNEDBY123;RENTEDBY1231;IDENTITY1231
124;STREET124;COLONY124;AREA124;OWNEDBY124;RENTEDBY124;IDENTITY124
125;STREET125;COLONY125;AREA125;OWNEDBY125;RENTEDBY125;IDENTITY125
111;STREET111;COLONY111;AREA111;OWNEDBY111;RENTEDBY1111;IDENTITY1111